# Flexbox: how to combine variable and fixed widths

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve a grid with three columns:

- The first column is 50% in width
- The second and third column combined are also 50% in width
- The third columns width is variable; it should grow however it seems fit (it contains one button with variable text).

If column three ends up taking x% of width than column two should be 50-x% in width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the first item `flex-basis: 50%` and the middle `flex-grow: 1`.

This will make the first 50% wide, the last as wide as its content and the middle fill the remaining space left

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .item {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}

.wrapper .item:first-child {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.wrapper .item:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">50%
  </div>
  <div class="item">Fill remaining
  </div>
  <div class="item">Button
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I made the mistake of trying to set some sort of 'auto' value to the third column. Will accept answer in a few minutes once SO allows it.